# Page with Ajax function does not refresh data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, partial-page-refresh

My scripts are working perfectly fine. However, the content does not refresh itself to get new data. Why is it so?

```
 function updateMsg() {
    $.ajax({
       url: "/recent/notifications/",
       cache: false,
       success: function(html){     
         $("#profile_notifarea_msgbox").html(html);
       }
    });
    setTimeout('updateMsg()', 4000);
 }
 updateMsg();
```

Comment: More details? Your content doesn't refresh? I don't get it.

Comment: Shouldn't make any difference, but your "setTimeout" call can be just `setTimeout(updateMsg, 4000);`.  What does FireBug show for the response from the ajax call?

Comment: ...Is there new data to display?

Comment: Is your content coming back through the AJAX call properly? Have you checked the content through Firebug with Firefox? Amazing tool for things like this if you haven't got it.

Comment: Is your success callback executing? Is profile_notifarea_msgbox the correct id for the element you are updating? Not sure if it's a typo and is supposed to be profile_notifyarea_msgbox.

Comment: @Pointy how do i see the ajax call from firebug? Can you provide the instructions?

Comment: @Gregin its correct, i am able to post my chat, see new chat. Only thing is, page does not refresh by itself

Comment: Consider using setInterval instead: http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setTimeout can reference updateMsg directly instead of using a string:

```
var timeout;

function updateMsg() {
   $.ajax({
      url: "/recent/notifications/",
      cache: false,
      success: function(html){     
        $("#profile_notifarea_msgbox").html(html);
        timeout = setTimeout(updateMsg, 4000);
      }
   });       
}
updateMsg();   

function stopUpdate() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}
```

To stop the continuous update you save a reference to the setTimeout in a variable and then call clearTimeout and pass in that variable. In this example, you would just call the function stopUpdate() to cancel the updates.

Comment: If you put the updateMsg() inside the Success callback, wouldn't that suffice? I assume the idea is to update the page after the data is returned so you can probably do away with the timeout all together.

Comment: @Luke Then it would call again instantly as soon as it gets a result. Depending on how fast the response is from the webserver it could be firing off ajax requests many times a second.

Comment: @infernal whats the difference between your line of code and mine? I do have $(document).ready too just that its too long to put it here

Comment: @pivotal Only that it passes the function to setTimeout instead of a string. Which is a better way of doing it. Does the updateMsg function get repeatedly called? You can check by putting a break point in in firebug or just adding an alert. I've updated the answer to show the code I could use.

Comment: @infernalBadger excellent insight here. It turns out when i use my own code, the alert does not trigger more than twice. However, with your line of code the alert pops continuously every 4 seconds. Therefore, i believe it is working now..thank you :)

Comment: @infernalBadger i do have another question now. How do i stop this setTimeout() method if i want specify a certain function to trigger a stop?

Comment: @pivotal You can use clearTimeout for that. I will add an example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

when you use ajax with jQuery try to always put an error function, in this way you can identify if something is wrong with the request